# SQL not properly ended in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, job-scheduling

I have a SQL Job / Schedular and it shows me when try to execute.

> > SQL Command not properly ended.

### My Code

```
BEGIN
dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name => 'LBN_Service',
                          job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
                          job_action => '
                                         BEGIN
                                          update TBL_LBN_Data nr
                                          SET ISACTIVE = 0
                                          WHERE sysdate > nr.PERIODTO
                                          END;',
                          start_date => systimestamp,
                          repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;BYHOUR=0;BYMINUTE=0;',
                          enabled => TRUE);
 END;
```

Comment: Maybe you need a semi-comma after `update TBL_LBN_Data nr
                                          SET ISACTIVE = 0
                                          WHERE sysdate > nr.PERIODTO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a semi-colon after `Update` statement

```
BEGIN
dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name => 'LBN_Service',
                          job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
                          job_action => 'BEGIN
                                         update TBL_LBN_Data nr
                                         SET ISACTIVE = 0
                                         WHERE sysdate > nr.PERIODTO;
                                         END;',
                          start_date => systimestamp,
                          repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;BYHOUR=0;BYMINUTE=0;',
                          enabled => TRUE);
 END;
```

Comment: It shows me this error : 11:48:36 Info: Job #264 could not be executed.  ORA-12011: execution of 1 jobs failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_IJOB", line 648
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_JOB", line 284
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: @TechGuy Look at the alert log for details on which jobs failed and why